# struct field assignment difference of pointer/non-pointer type

Tags: go

In section 4.4 (Structs) of The Go Programming Language, there is a code excerpt:

```
var dilbert Employee
func EmployeeByID(id int) *Employee { /* ... */ }
id := dilbert.ID
EmployeeByID(id).salary = 0
```

with the remark

> If the result type of `EmployeeByID` were changed to `Employee` instead of `*Employee`, the assignment statement would not compile since its left-hand side would not identify a variable.

I don't understand why changing the result type of `EmployeeByID` to `Employee` would cause LHS not identify a variable.

Comment: This simplified example demonstrates the issue: http://play.golang.org/p/fDlTowmJOy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [simplified example](http://play.golang.org/p/fDlTowmJOy) demonstrates the issue:

```
package main

type t struct {
    int
}

func newT() *t { return &t{} }
//func newT() t { return t{} }

func main() {
    newT().int = 0
}
```

My guess is that if you use the version of `newT` that does not return a pointer, and never save off a reference to the result of `newT()`, then setting the value of its `int` field can never meaningfully do anything.  It's similar to setting an unused variable.

If instead you the non-pointer version of `newT` but you have something like:

```
x := newT()
x.int = 0
```

Then you'd be fine.

Alternatively, using the pointer version of `newT` above is fine, because it could be returning some state you already had defined previously, see [example](http://play.golang.org/p/jzdLkZOTO3):

```
package main

type t struct {
    int
}

var dilbert = &t{3}

func newT() *t { return dilbert }

//func newT() t { return t{} }

func main() {
    println(dilbert.int)
    newT().int = 0
    println(dilbert.int)
}
```

Comment: After seeing you simplified example, it is more clear to me now and I think you answer is reasonable. Your "never save off a reference" is what they called non-addressable in the book, and I guess that's why you can't access the field without saving the new struct as a variable first.

Answer (score 2):

I have researched on this topic, and I think the problem if you change to Employee instead of *Employee, then EmployeeByID(id) will be a unaddressable value since it is not assigned to a variable. It is OK if you assign it a variable like below:

```
e1 := EmployeeByID(id)
e1.Salary = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func EmployeeByID(id int) *Employee { /* ... */ }
```

This return a pointer to an Employee variable.

```
func EmployeeByID(id int) Employee { /* ... */ }
```

This returns a **value** copied from an Employee variable. You need to assign it to a variable before using it.